# The equal signs after aligning are too far from the equation

Tags: align

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2}(2f(x)-g(x))&=5\\
    \Leftrightarrow &\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2}2f(x)-\lim_{x \to 2}g(x)&=5\tag{limit laws}\\
    \Leftrightarrow &\displaystyle 2\cdot\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)-\lim_{x \to 2}g(x)&=5\tag{limit laws}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use `&` to align the equals signs but it's too far from the equation. How solve it?

Comment: You should use `alignat`, but the “if and only if” symbols are wrong, because that's *not* what the limit laws say and it's very easy to make an example where the top limit exists, but the middle ones don't.

Comment: @egreg if I remove the limit law tag and add under the first limit "applying limit law, we have:". Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `align`-like environments, `&` is a group separator. Each group has two elements with `right & left` alignment with an inner separator which is also `&`. You just need to play with ampersands `&` to achieve the desired effect. Most of times this pattern

```
% item && item && item ... etc.
```

will give you left alignment for all items.

In this case, I applied `alignat`, which in oppose to `align` does not add extra space. However, I also had to simulate a space in one group by adding `\` . Note, `alignat` requires a mandatory argument: a number of groups.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &                && \ \lim_{x \to 2}2f(x)-g(x)                    &&=5 \\
  &\Leftrightarrow && \ \lim_{x \to 2}2f(x)-\lim_{x \to 2}g(x)      &&=5 \tag{limit laws} \\
  &\Leftrightarrow && \ 2\cdot\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)-\lim_{x \to 2}g(x) &&=5 \tag{limit laws}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```