# How do I align a set of chemical formulae

Tags: align, chemistry, chemformula

Here's the image I want to recreate -
[image]

Here's my attempt at recreating it -

```
\documentclass{12pt}{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \ce{Cl^{.} + CH4 -> CH3^{.} + HCl} \\
    \ce{CH3^{.} + Cl2 -> CH3Cl + Cl^{.}} \\ \\
    \ce{Cl^{.} + CH4 -> CH3^{.} + HCl} \\
    \ce{CH3^{.} + Cl2 -> CH3Cl + Cl^{.}} \\ \\
    \ce{Cl^{.} + CH4 -> CH3^{.} + HCl} \\
    \ce{CH3^{.} + Cl2 -> CH3Cl + Cl^{.}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

this yields -

[image]

Any ideas on how I can insert the red circles and lines?

Comment: I only know how to align it along the arrows; you just insert `&` before each symbol `->` but for dots [mhchem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package seems to be using `.` or `*` for dots next to chemical symbols and typeset them in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar using "chemfig"

```
\documentclass[border={4mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{f}{$\displaystyle\aligned}{\endaligned$}

\begin{document}

\begin{f}
&\schemestart
\chemfig{@{a}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}} \+ \chemfig{CH_4}  \arrow{->} \chemfig{\charge{0=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{HC\ell}
\schemestop
\\
%
& \schemestart
%
\chemfig{\charge{180=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{C\ell_2} \arrow{->} \chemfig{CH_3C\ell} \+ \chemfig{@{b}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}}
\schemestop
\\ \\
&\schemestart
\chemfig{@{c}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}} \+ \chemfig{CH_4}  \arrow{->} \chemfig{\charge{0=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{HC\ell}
\schemestop
\\
%
& \schemestart
%
\chemfig{\charge{180=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{C\ell_2} \arrow{->} \chemfig{CH_3C\ell} \+ \chemfig{@{d}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}}
\schemestop
\\ \\
&\schemestart
\chemfig{@{e}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}} \+ \chemfig{CH_4}  \arrow{->} \chemfig{\charge{0=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{HC\ell}
\schemestop
\\
%
& \schemestart
%
\chemfig{\charge{180=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{C\ell_2} \arrow{->} \chemfig{CH_3C\ell} \+ \chemfig{@{f}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}}
\schemestop
\\ \\
    % myedge={right}   para meia seta  
%\begin{tikzpicture}
    \chemmove{
    \draw[red,dotted](a) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](b) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](c) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](d) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](e) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](f) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,shorten <=6pt,shorten >=6pt](b).. controls +(240:16mm) and +(60:16mm)..(c);
    \draw[red,shorten <=6pt,shorten >=6pt](d).. controls +(240:16mm) and +(60:16mm)..(e);
}
\end{f}
\end{document}
```

[image]

this code will align the arrows

```
\documentclass[border={4mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{f}{$\displaystyle\aligned}{\endaligned$}

\begin{document}

\begin{f}
\schemestart
\chemfig{@{a}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}} \+ \chemfig{CH_4} \schemestop  & \schemestart \arrow{->} \chemfig{\charge{0=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{HC\ell}
\schemestop
\\
%
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{\charge{180=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{C\ell_2} \schemestop & \schemestart \arrow{->} \chemfig{CH_3C\ell} \+ \chemfig{@{b}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}}
\schemestop
\\ \\
\schemestart
\chemfig{@{c}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}} \+ \chemfig{CH_4}\schemestop   & \schemestart \arrow{->} \chemfig{\charge{0=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{HC\ell}
\schemestop
\\
%
 \schemestart
%
\chemfig{\charge{180=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{C\ell_2}\schemestop &  \schemestart \arrow{->} \chemfig{CH_3C\ell} \+ \chemfig{@{d}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}}
\schemestop
\\ \\
\schemestart
\chemfig{@{e}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}} \+ \chemfig{CH_4} \schemestop &\schemestart \arrow{->} \chemfig{\charge{0=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{HC\ell}
\schemestop
\\
%
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{\charge{180=\.}{CH_3}} \+ \chemfig{C\ell_2} \schemestop & \schemestart \arrow{->} \chemfig{CH_3C\ell} \+ \chemfig{@{f}\charge{0=\.}{C\ell}}
\schemestop
%------------------------------------------------------
    \chemmove{
    \draw[red,dotted](a) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](b) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](c) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](d) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](e) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,dotted](f) circle (.35);
    \draw[red,shorten <=6pt,shorten >=6pt](b).. controls +(240:16mm) and +(60:16mm)..(c);
    \draw[red,shorten <=6pt,shorten >=6pt](d).. controls +(240:16mm) and +(60:16mm)..(e);
}
\end{f}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I checked the package [mhchem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem). It seems adding `*` or `.` next to a symbol generates a dot with vertical alignment with respect to a symbol. It seems to do what you are looking for.

For the alignment, use `&` as a separator around which LaTeX will align left and right parts (see my previous comments on a similar problem: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659082/the-equal-signs-after-aligning-are-too-far-from-the-equation/659085#659085) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654971/how-to-align-equations-in-two-columns/654975#654975) or wiki about [alignat](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Other_environments) or [align](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align*)).

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample chapter}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{alignat*}{3}
    \ce{  & Cl* + CH4  &->&* && CH3 + HCl} \\
    \ce{* & CH3 + Cl2  &->&  && CH3Cl + Cl*} \\[12pt]
    \ce{  & Cl* + CH4  &->&* && CH3 + HCl} \\
    \ce{* & CH3 + Cl2  &->&  && CH3Cl + Cl*} \\[12pt]
    \ce{  & Cl* + CH4  &->&* && CH3 + HCl} \\
    \ce{* & CH3 + Cl2  &->&  && CH3Cl + Cl*}
  \end{alignat*}
  \caption{The propagation step is repeated over again and again.}\label{fig:propagation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```